# How to move data in sale.order.line to delivery order (stock.pack.operation)

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I would like to move the description of the product on sale order line to the delivery order line (stock.pack.operation).

I added this code in the "action_confirm" of the sale.order

> order.picking_ids.pack_operation_product_ids.write ({' my_field_in_stock_pack_operation': order_line.order.name})

for a product that is already successful. But if more than 1 will occur error..

is there a way or another solution?

i am using odoo 10

Answer (score 1):

```
for order in self:
    if order.picking_ids
        for picking in picking_ids:
            if picking.order_line.name:
                self.env['stock.move.operation.link'].write{'my_field_in_stock_pack_operation': picking.order_line.name})
```

OR
on sale order confirm create [stock.picking] on action_confirm method where you can create description field.

Comment: thx sir, BTW, where do I put the code above?
whether in action_confirm sale order?

Comment: I lay it on the action_confirm sale order still can not

Comment: have you create field on stock.move.operation.link ?

Comment: field name - my_field_in_stock_pack_operation and field type is Char. on tree view of delivery order line add field my_field_in_stock_pack_operation

Comment: Yet, what should I make on stock.move.operation.link? What is the only field of type char?